# Can you set multiple paints on the same XYPlot?

Tags: jfreechart

So I have a working XYPlot but I want to add different colors to the background, not a single one. I know this appears to be doable for quadrants, but I want it basically row by row, or ranges of rows I should say.

Basically something like this : [image]

but with ideally 3-4 colors instead of just 2. Can you set the background paint for a specified Axis range for example? I haven't found any info or way to do it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IntervalMarker`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/IntervalMarker.html) "Represents an interval to be highlighted in some way." In the example below, two markers span the plot's range.

```
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(…);
plot.addRangeMarker(new IntervalMarker(.3, 1, new Color(0x60CCFFE5, true)));
plot.addRangeMarker(new IntervalMarker(0, .3, new Color(0x60FFCCE5, true)));
```

[image]

Comment: Just the man I was hoping an answer from! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much, sir.