# How to keep an icon in one side of a chart in JFreeChart Java

Tags: java, annotations, icons, jfreechart

I have the following chart:

[image]

The chart is dynamic and has the capability of make zoom in and zoom out.
I want to put an icon that is created as:

```
BufferedImage triangleIcon = null;
        try {
            triangleIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/Imagenes/triangulo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

And can be placed in any point as:

```
xyannotation = new XYImageAnnotation(XValue, YValue, triangleIcon);
this.xyplot.addAnnotation(xyannotation);
```

I want to put this icon at any Y value but always next to the left side of the chart, without taking into account the zoom. Something like:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: I know little about JFreeChart, but a generic solution would be to draw an image over top of the chart (For example on a different layer or glass pane).

Comment: i'm thinking that actually the X value that i want to have the icon is the left limit axis value, so if I get to obtain this I would already have it, any idea about how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sorifiend's suggestion is sound but probably unnecessary; just remember that `XYImageAnnotation` requires _data_ coordinates, rather than __screen_ coordinates, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71801198/230513). Also consider an `XYShapeAnnotation` instead.

Comment: What would its position be "without taking into account the zoom?" Half-way? I guess you could override `XYPlot::draw`.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland the X position must to be the left border of the chart frame always and with any Y value

Comment: If you don't want override `XYPlot::draw`, I guess you could add an `AnnotationChangeListener` and update the position to what you want.

Comment: Maybe two `IntervalMarker`s, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879705/230513).

Comment: @trashgod this isn´t useful for my application, IntervalMarkers are for modify the background. I need a triangle as a figure, where I can set coordinates. But thanks for your support

Comment: How would it differ from an `XYShapeAnnotation`?

Comment: both XYShapeAnnotation and XYImageAnnotation have similar options regarding to positioning. With both I have the same problem, I don't know how can I put the Image in one side of the frame chart ignoring the values of the X axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you want to annotate "one side of the…chart, ignoring the value of the *X* axis". Ordinarily, such [annotations](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) specify both coordinates in *data* space. One approach is a custom annotation that extends the abstract parent, [`AbstractXYAnnotation`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/AbstractXYAnnotation.html). Override `draw()` to transform the vertical *data* coordinate to the corresponding *screen* coordinate, while pinning the horizontal *screen* coordinate to the `dataArea` of the plot. Pan and zoom to see the effect.

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
…
@Override
public void draw(…) {
    RectangleEdge rangeEdge = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();
    double y = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(yValue, dataArea, rangeEdge);
    at.setToIdentity();
    at.translate(dataArea.getX() + 1, y);
    …
}
```

[image: Annotation]

Example code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.AbstractXYAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.RectangleEdge;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72311226/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71780485/230513
 */
public class XYShapeTest {

    private static final int N = 18_000;
    private static final int SIZE = 16;
    private final Shape pointer = createPolygon(SIZE);

    private static class AxisAnnotation extends AbstractXYAnnotation {

        private final AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        private final Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(4f);
        private final Shape shape;
        private final double yValue;

        public AxisAnnotation(Shape shape, double y) {
            this.shape = shape;
            this.yValue = y;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2, XYPlot plot, Rectangle2D dataArea,
            ValueAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis,
            int rendererIndex, PlotRenderingInfo info) {
            RectangleEdge rangeEdge = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();
            double y = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(yValue, dataArea, rangeEdge);
            at.setToIdentity();
            at.translate(dataArea.getX() + 1, y);
            g2.setStroke(stroke);
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
            g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(shape));
        }
    }

    private Shape createPolygon(int size) {
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(0, 0);
        p.addPoint(0, 1);
        p.addPoint(2, 0);
        p.addPoint(0, -1);
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(size, size);
        return at.createTransformedShape(p);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series");
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i += 1_000) {
            series.add(i / 1_000, i);
        }
        return new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test", "X", "Y", dataset);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(true);
        plot.addAnnotation(new AxisAnnotation(pointer, 9_000));
        return chart;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("XYShapeTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(createChart(createDataset())) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 300);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new XYShapeTest()::display);
    }
}
```